# How can I get the payload from calling YouTube API V3?

Tags: node.js, next.js, youtube-api

I am trying to get data from a YouTube channel using Youtube API V3. The code below fetches various data points but when I tried running the app I did not see the payload ('items') array in my response object nor did I get an 'error'. This is what I saw instead:

```
 {
  kind: 'youtube#channelListResponse',
  etag: 'PqCO86vmlUDWFiOBSqOsOZRp5jE',
  pageInfo: { totalResults: 0, resultsPerPage: 50 }
}
```

My code looks like this - what am I doing wrong?

```
const Youtube = ({ youtubeDataJson }) => {
  console.log(youtubeDataJson);
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>This should log the data</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  //Base Url
  const gBaseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3";
  const channelName = "ThePrimeagen";

  //  fetching data
  const youtubeData = await fetch(
    `${gBaseUrl}/channels?part=snippet&part=contentDetails&part=statistics&part=contentOwnerDetails&forUsername=${channelName}&maxResults=50&key=${process.env.YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`
  );
  const youtubeDataJson = await youtubeData.json();

  //Return data
  return {
    props: {
      youtubeDataJson
    }
  };
}

export default Youtube;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that totalResults is 0. You will not receive an items property if you have 0 results. This happens when you enter a forUsername that is not found. In your code above `ThePrimeagen` is not a username.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but the channel does exist: https://www.youtube.com/c/ThePrimeagen , and I'm guessing that is the username is also the channel name. I have also tried with a few other channel names, and they have all returned the same issue.

Comment: That's not a username. It's a custom name you can choose when you get over 100 subscribers, but it is not a username (or channel ID). The c in the url stands for custom, not channel.

Comment: Try using the channel ID as forUsername for that custom URL: UCUyeluBRhGPCW4rPe_UvBZQ

Comment: Thank you for your response. Very much appreciated

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer to help others. Upvote if useful too. Thanks.